# How to convert dataframe to time series with detecting periods in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a csv-file with a column with number of hours (integer format) and four other columns with hourly data in character format. The data has been collected for 48 hours and is periodic for every 24 hours.

```
Hours  A     B     C     D
  0   130    17    75   139
  1   124    16    69   129
  2   121    16    67   125
  3   121    16    66   127
  4   123    16    66   128
  5   127    16    69   130
  6   135    18    77   138
  7   150    20    89   152
  8   159    21    95   160
  9   162    22    94   165
 10   161    22    94   166
 11   161    22    94   169
 12   161    22    94   172
 13   159    22    93   172
 14   157    22    93   170
 15   154    21    92   168
 16   152    21    91   167
 17   151    21    92   162
 18   152    21    92   162
 19   152    21    92   157
 20   154    21    93   158
 21   162    22    99   163
 22   164    22    95   167
 23   155    20    87   157
 24   145    19    78   147
 ...
 48   144    19    76   147
```

I have saved the data in R like that:

```
> df <- read.csv2("data.csv", na="NA", header=TRUE)
> class(df)
> [1] "data.frame"
> class(df$Hours)
> [1] "integer"
> class(df$A)
> [1] "character"
```

Now the question: How can I convert the dataframe into a time series and how can R detect a period for every 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to reset your sequence after every `24 hours` then you can do like this

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(old = 1:1000) %>% 
  mutate(new = old %% 24)
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
#>      old   new
#>    <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1
#>  2     2     2
#>  3     3     3
#>  4     4     4
#>  5     5     5
#>  6     6     6
#>  7     7     7
#>  8     8     8
#>  9     9     9
#> 10    10    10
#> # … with 990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I don't want to reset the sequence, but to make a time series out of it, which has two periods in 48 hours.

Comment: Can you show us how the output should look like

Comment: I have no idea how the output should look like, but I want to convert the data into a time series, so that class(df) is "ts" and I can decompose the time series.